# Django redirect to custom URL

Tags: python, ios, django, oauth-2.0, custom-url

From my Django app, how to I redirect a user to somescheme://someurl.com?

To give you some context in case it helps, I have a working oauth2 server written in Python/Django and I need to allow users to register redirect_uris that have a custom URL scheme. This custom URL scheme is used for [handling the redirect within native apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW20).

My first reaction was to use an HttpResponseRedirect, but this URL has a custom scheme and isn't HTTP so I'm guessing this is not what I want. Thanks in advance for any advice you can give.

Edit:
I did try this and Django returns the response redirect correctly without throwing an error, but the browser does not redirect to this URL. I'm using Chrome to test this.

Edit 2:
HttpResponseRedirect works fine in safari.

Comment: Have you tried it? The redirect response goes back to the client, so it might just work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> class HttpResponseRedirect
>
> The first argument to the constructor is required -- the path to redirect to. This can >be a fully qualified URL (e.g. 'http://www.yahoo.com/search/') or an absolute path with no >domain (e.g. '/search/'). See HttpResponse for other optional constructor arguments. Note >that this returns an HTTP status code 302.

This is from here: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/

It should work anyway from what I'm reading.

Answer (score 19):

This actually **should not** work as Django is only allowing redirects to `http`, `https` and `ftp` by default for security reasons:

https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2012/jul/30/security-releases-issued/

I was having the same issue with OAuth and redirect to custom schemes.
Django (on Apache) is throwing 500's (`django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousOperation`) when redirecting to custom schemes. The solution is to create your own `HttpResponseRedirect` subclass or just do:

```
location = < your redirect URL >
res = HttpResponse(location, status=302)
res['Location'] = location
return res
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I haven't tried this yet but will mark it correct if I do and it works. I was on Django 1.4.0 which is probably why I didn't notice this problem.

Comment: Just to add to this, I found (for Django 1.6), that if you subclass `HttpResponseRedirect` you also need to add your custom protocol[s] to the `allowed_schemes` class variable, otherwise Django will still raise `SuspiciousOperation`