# How to redirect to external URL in Django?

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, external-url

I think this should be easy, but I cannot figure it out. I am trying to write an opt-out view. I am receiving a get request. Through urls.py, I render my opt-out view. In this view, I save some parameters for the user in the database and then I want to redirect the user to an external URL. I tried:

```
return redirect('http://stackoverflow.com/')
```

from [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect). However, the optout view renders the training template instead of returning the redirect, though the parameters are saved in the database as expected. My code is as follows:

```
def optout(request):
    if (('REMOTE_USER' in request.META and request.META['REMOTE_USER'] != "") or 
        (request.session.get('userid', False) and request.session['userid'] != "")):
        if ('REMOTE_USER' in request.META and request.META['REMOTE_USER'] != ""):
            userid = request.META['REMOTE_USER']
        if (request.session.get('userid', False) and request.session['userid'] != ""):
            userid = request.session['userid']
        user = User.objects.get(username=userid)
        user.optout = True
        user.postpone = False
        user.save()
        return redirect('http://stackoverflow.com/')
    context = { 'userid': "" }
    return render(request, 'games/Training.html', context)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by _it does not work_?  The optout view renders the Training template instead of returning the redirect?

Comment: @JohnGordon, yes. You're right. The optout view renders the Training template instead of returning the redirect, though the parameters are saved in the database as expected.

Comment: similiar question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326504/django-redirect-to-custom-url)

Comment: If it's rendering the Training template, then very likely your top `if` statement is evaluating to false (and thus redirect is never called).  The database save must be happening elsewhere.  Try putting in some logging statements.

Comment: Did you import redirect? from django.shortcuts import redirect

Answer (score 38):

Yeah, `return redirect('http://stackoverflow.com/')` is the correct method.

If you do the following, you can confirm that is a working method to redirect.

```
   from django.shortcuts import redirect

   def optout(request):
       return redirect("http://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Your conditional statements must not be catching.

Comment: Yes Gator_Python. Thank you for your response. I checked the database for a number of times and both parameters are saved correctly.

Comment: So, what's happening instead of the expected redirect?

Comment: The optout view renders the Training template instead of returning the redirect, though the parameters are saved in the database as expected.

Comment: Instead of checking your database, try printing out the conditionals you're checking for to see if they match what you expect. Or change that conditional to `if True` just for the sake of proving the `return redirect` portion is working. 

Then we can narrow our scope to figure out why those aren't catching, which is what I suspect is happening.

Comment: Is there a way we could open the link on a new tab, as we do it in HTML using  `_blank`?

Answer (score 18):

using class **HttpResponseRedirect**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def out(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("http://google.com")
```

Or:

using class **HttpResponse**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def out(request):
    response = HttpResponse("", status=302)
    response['Location'] = "scheme://host"
    return response
```

**NOTE:**

> The last one is useful to redirect from a website to a mobile
> (Android/Iphone) app. Where location is `scheme://host`